# How to enable SSL in MVC 6 application?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

In Visual Studio 2015, when we select the MVC6 web application, the **Properties** window contains no **SSL Enabled** property.

So what is the correct way to run a MVC6 application in SSL?

---

Since we can create pure Html + JavaScript site with the empty MVC 6 Application, can we enable SSL without using `RequireHttpsAttribute` that only comes with MVC?

Answer (score 1):

In your Startup.cs file  `options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());`

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
    {
    .......
    }


    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            .....
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                "default",
                "{controller)/{action}",
                 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                );
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. What if the application is not using Mvc. Just a static html, like a pure client-side angular app. There would be no `RequireHttpsAttribute()` from the Mvc namespace. Is there a universal method to set up SSL?

Comment: not quite sure what is the setup process with angular, not a lot of docs available for now...

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that needs to be done to enable SSL on the HTML/JavaScript side assuming your web server is set up with a certificate and proper bindings, and the firewall is configured properly.

If you are asking how to redirect to HTTPS automatically, it can be done using JavaScript. Put something like this in a JavaScript file that is referenced at the top of each page.

```
if (window.location.protocol.toLowerCase() != "https:") {
    window.location.href = "https:" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
}
```